# styleSheet QComboBox QListView not working after convert UI to PY

Tags: pycharm, pyqt5, qt-designer, qcombobox, qlistview

I created my first UI using Qt Designer and convert UI to PY.
The styleSheets `QComboBox QListView` and `QComboBox QAbstractItemView` are not working after converting.
But in Qt Designer all styleSheet `QComboBox` is working.
I using Python 3.9.13 and PyCharm Community Edition.

```
QComboBox {
    border: 2px solid #0d7377;
    border-radius: 20;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #eeeeee;
}
QComboBox::drop-down {
    border: 0px;
}
QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(:/iconic/arrow.png);
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    selection-background-color: #1a1a1a;
    selection-color: #eeeeee;
}
QComboBox QListView {
    border: 2px solid #0d7377;
    border-radius: 15;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #0d7377;
    outline: 0px;
}
```

[in Qt Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHE8j.png)

[after convert ui to py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZHOo.png)

[styleSheet in PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW5tQ.png)

I only tried delete one at a time line in styleSheets `QComboBox QListView` and `QComboBox QAbstractItemView` in PyCharm to understand which line gives the error, but it did not give results.

Comment: First of all, don't post code as images, but as text. Then, provide a [mre] (the ui file, only including what's necessary: the combo box and its styling).

Comment: I created new ui and convert to py to send it to you, but new ui with combobox with stylesheet in py is working, but in my project this is not working either

Comment: Then you're probably close to finding the cause of the issue, that's also another reason for which a MRE is almost always required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any font change in Combobox using the properties editor breaking normal its operation. Change the font in the style sheet

```
QComboBox {
    font: bold 12pt "Microsoft YaHei";
    border: 2px solid #0d7377;
    border-radius: 20;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #eeeeee;
}
```